getting data from firestore but there is problem with date field
fetching data from Firestore but the problem is in date field

dateCreated :  Timestamp nanoseconds :  518000000 seconds :  1722162236 [[Prototype]] :  Object dislikes :  1

    const docSnap = await getDoc(docref);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log(docSnap.data());
      setDocument(docSnap.data());
      setDocumentDate(Document.dateCreated);
      console.log(DocumentDate);
    } else {
      console.log("Document does not exist");
    }


undefined
I have no idea why this is happening

If your document has a dateCreated field that you want to print, you access that with docSnap.data().dateCreated. So
setDocumentDate(docSnap.data().dateCreated);


You say that you are "getting undefined as output" but you aren't.
You are getting an object value for the first console.log() and you are getting undefined for the second console.log().
The second console.log() is attempting to render the value of DocumentDate which, assuming from the fact that you call setDocumentDate(), is a state variable.
You want to realize that the "set state function" in NextJS/React is an asynchronous function.  When you call it, JS puts the work to be done on the "asynch queue" and continues to your next line of code.  The value of the state variable will not be updated until AFTER the current rendering of the component completes.
So setDocument(docSnap.data()) will not set a value of Document right away.  setDocumentDate(Document.dateCreated) will get undefined since Document does not yet have a value, and even if there was a value in Document the call to console.log(DocumentDate) would render undefined because there is no value set in DocumentDate yet.
